# VHDL Component Port Mapping Issues

Tags: vhdl

I am new to dealing with using COMPONENTS in VHDL and I understand how to port map simple things like slowing down a clock, however I have built a sequence dtetctor that seems to work well, but I want to have its' output trigger an input in my LCD write program and display to my LCD screen.  How can I port map only the one signal over, or is there a better way of thinking about using the COMPONENT that I'm not thinking of?

How do i do direct entity instantiation?  Could I use that here?  I have been trying different ways to make my output Z be the input for the LCD on enable_0 but cant figure out how to not mess with all the other ports on that entity.

Thanks all

Matt

```
--Sequence detector(Mealy Machine-resetting)
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

ENTITY Sequence_Detector IS PORT(
    X : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 DOWNTO 0);
    CLK, LOAD: IN STD_LOGIC;
    LED : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(17 DOWNTO 0);
    Z: INOUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0));
END ENTITY;

ARCHITECTURE BEH OF Sequence_Detector IS
    TYPE state_type is (S0,S1,S2,S3,S4,S5,S6,S7,S8);
    SIGNAL TMP : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 DOWNTO 0);
    SIGNAL clkout : STD_LOGIC;
    SIGNAL state : state_type;

    COMPONENT slowclk PORT(
        clk : IN STD_LOGIC;
        clkout : OUT STD_LOGIC);
    END COMPONENT;

BEGIN
    LED(17) <= LOAD;
    LED(8 DOWNTO 0) <= X;
    TMP <= X;

    state0: slowclk PORT MAP (clk, clkout);
    PROCESS (CLK)
    BEGIN
        IF (LOAD = '1') THEN
            IF (clkout'EVENT AND clkout = '1') THEN
                CASE state IS
                    WHEN S0 =>
                        IF X(8) = '0' THEN
                            state <= S0;      --1--
                            Z <= "00";
                        ELSE
                            state <= S1;
                            Z <= "00";
                        END IF;

                    WHEN S1 =>
                        IF X(7) = '0' THEN
                            state <= S0;      --1--
                            Z <= "00";
                        ELSE
                            state <= S2;
                            Z <= "00";
                        END IF;

                    WHEN S2 =>
                        IF X(6) = '0' THEN
                            state <= S3;      --0--
                            Z <= "00";
                        ELSE
                            state <= S2;
                            Z <= "00";
                        END IF;

                    WHEN S3 =>
                        IF X(5) = '0' THEN
                            state <= S0;      --1--
                            Z <= "00";
                        ELSE
                            state <= S4;
                            Z <= "00";
                        END IF;

                    WHEN S4 =>
                        IF X(4) = '0' THEN
                            state <= S5;      --0--
                            Z <= "00";
                        ELSE
                            state <= S2;
                            Z <= "00";
                        END IF;

                    WHEN S5 =>
                        IF X(3) = '0' THEN
                            state <= S6;      --0--
                            Z <= "00";
                        ELSE
                            state <= S0;
                            Z <= "00";
                        END IF;

                    WHEN S6 =>
                        IF X(2) = '0' THEN
                            state <= S0;      --1--
                            Z <= "00";
                        ELSE
                            state <= S7;
                            Z <= "00";
                        END IF;

                    WHEN S7 =>
                        IF X(1) = '0' THEN
                            state <= S0;      --1--
                            Z <= "00";
                        ELSE
                            state <= S8;
                            Z <= "00";
                        END IF;

                    WHEN S8 =>
                        IF X(0) = '0' THEN
                            state <= S0;      --0--
                            Z <= "11";
                        ELSE
                            state <= S2;
                            Z <= "01";
                        END IF;
                END CASE;
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END PROCESS;
END BEH;

LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

ENTITY slowclk IS PORT(
    clk : IN STD_LOGIC;
    clkout : OUT STD_LOGIC);
END slowclk;

ARCHITECTURE ckt OF slowclk IS
BEGIN
    PROCESS(clk)
        VARIABLE cnt : INTEGER RANGE 0 TO 50000000;
    BEGIN
        IF clk'EVENT AND clk='1' THEN
            IF cnt=50000000 THEN
                cnt:=0;
                clkout<='1';
            ELSE
                cnt:=cnt+1;
                clkout<='0';
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END PROCESS;
END ckt;

LIBRARY IEEE;
USE  IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
USE  IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.all;
USE  IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.all;

ENTITY LCD IS
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
    --                        ASCII HEX TABLE
    --  Hex                 Low Hex Digit
    -- Value  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   A   B   C   D   E   F
    ------\----------------------------------------------------------------
    --H  2 |  SP  !   "   #   $   %   &   '   (   )   *   +   ,   -   .   /
    --i  3 |  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   :   ;   <   =   >   ?
    --g  4 |  @   A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N   O
    --h  5 |  P   Q   R   S   T   U   V   W   X   Y   Z   [   \   ]   ^   _
    --   6 |  `   a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k   l   m   n   o
    --   7 |  p   q   r   s   t   u   v   w   x   y   z   {   |   }   ~ DEL
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
PORT(
    reset, CLOCK_50        : IN  STD_LOGIC;
    enable_0               : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0);
    enable_1               : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0);
    LCD_RS, LCD_E          : OUT STD_LOGIC;
    LCD_RW                 : OUT   STD_LOGIC;
    LCD_ON                 : OUT STD_LOGIC;
    LCD_BLON               : OUT STD_LOGIC;
    DATA_BUS               : INOUT  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0));
END ENTITY;

ARCHITECTURE Behavior OF LCD IS
    TYPE character_string IS ARRAY ( 0 TO 31 ) OF STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0 );

    TYPE STATE_TYPE IS (HOLD, FUNC_SET, DISPLAY_ON, MODE_SET, Print_String,
                   LINE2, RETURN_HOME, DROP_LCD_E, RESET1, RESET2,
                   RESET3, DISPLAY_OFF, DISPLAY_CLEAR);

    SIGNAL   state, next_command           : STATE_TYPE;
    SIGNAL   LCD_display_string            : character_string;
    SIGNAL   DATA_BUS_VALUE, Next_Char     : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
    SIGNAL   CLK_COUNT_400HZ               : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(19 DOWNTO 0);
    SIGNAL   CHAR_COUNT                 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 DOWNTO 0);
    SIGNAL   CLK_400HZ_Enable,LCD_RW_INT   : STD_LOGIC;
    SIGNAL   Line1_chars, Line2_chars      : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(127 DOWNTO 0);
BEGIN
    LCD_ON      <= '1';
    LCD_BLON    <= '1';

    PROCESS (clock_50)
    BEGIN
        CASE(enable_0) IS
            --passed--
            WHEN "11" => LCD_display_string <= (
                X"53",X"65",X"71",X"75",X"65",X"6E",X"63",X"65",X"20",X"50",X"61",X"73",X"73",X"65",X"64",X"20",
                X"4D",X"61",X"74",X"74",X"68",X"65",X"77",X"20",X"41",X"6E",X"64",X"65",X"72",X"73",X"6F",X"6E");
            WHEN "10" => LCD_display_string <= (
                X"20",X"20",X"20",X"20",X"45",X"45",X"43",X"45",X"20",X"33",X"34",X"33",X"20",X"20",X"20",X"20",
                X"4D",X"61",X"74",X"74",X"68",X"65",X"77",X"20",X"41",X"6E",X"64",X"65",X"72",X"73",X"6F",X"6E");
            --failed--
            WHEN "01" => LCD_display_string <= (
                X"53",X"65",X"71",X"75",X"65",X"6E",X"63",X"65",X"20",X"46",X"61",X"69",X"6C",X"65",X"64",X"20",
                X"4D",X"61",X"74",X"74",X"68",X"65",X"77",X"20",X"41",X"6E",X"64",X"65",X"72",X"73",X"6F",X"6E");
            WHEN "00" => LCD_display_string <= (
                X"20",X"20",X"20",X"20",X"45",X"45",X"43",X"45",X"20",X"33",X"34",X"33",X"20",X"20",X"20",X"20",
                X"4D",X"61",X"74",X"74",X"68",X"65",X"77",X"20",X"41",X"6E",X"64",X"65",X"72",X"73",X"6F",X"6E");
        END CASE;
    END PROCESS;

    -- BIDIRECTIONAL TRI STATE LCD DATA BUS
    DATA_BUS <= DATA_BUS_VALUE WHEN LCD_RW_INT = '0' ELSE "ZZZZZZZZ";

    -- get next character in display string
    Next_Char <= LCD_display_string(CONV_INTEGER(CHAR_COUNT));
    LCD_RW <= LCD_RW_INT;

    PROCESS
    BEGIN
        WAIT UNTIL CLOCK_50'EVENT AND CLOCK_50 = '1';
        IF RESET = '0' THEN
            CLK_COUNT_400HZ <= X"00000";
            CLK_400HZ_Enable <= '0';
        ELSE
            IF CLK_COUNT_400HZ < X"0F424" THEN
                CLK_COUNT_400HZ <= CLK_COUNT_400HZ + 1;
                CLK_400HZ_Enable <= '0';
            ELSE
                CLK_COUNT_400HZ <= X"00000";
                CLK_400HZ_Enable <= '1';
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END PROCESS;

    PROCESS (CLOCK_50, reset)
    BEGIN
        IF reset = '0' THEN
            state <= RESET1;
            DATA_BUS_VALUE <= X"38";
            next_command <= RESET2;
            LCD_E <= '1';
            LCD_RS <= '0';
            LCD_RW_INT <= '0';

        ELSIF CLOCK_50'EVENT AND CLOCK_50 = '1' THEN
            -- State Machine to send commands and data to LCD DISPLAY
            IF CLK_400HZ_Enable = '1' THEN
                CASE state IS
                    -- Set Function to 8-bit transfer and 2 line display with 5x8 Font size
                    -- see Hitachi HD44780 family data sheet for LCD command and timing details
                    WHEN RESET1 =>
                        LCD_E <= '1';
                        LCD_RS <= '0';
                        LCD_RW_INT <= '0';
                        DATA_BUS_VALUE <= X"38";
                        state <= DROP_LCD_E;
                        next_command <= RESET2;
                        CHAR_COUNT <= "00000";
                    WHEN RESET2 =>
                        LCD_E <= '1';
                        LCD_RS <= '0';
                        LCD_RW_INT <= '0';
                        DATA_BUS_VALUE <= X"38";
                        state <= DROP_LCD_E;
                        next_command <= RESET3;
                    WHEN RESET3 =>
                        LCD_E <= '1';
                        LCD_RS <= '0';
                        LCD_RW_INT <= '0';
                        DATA_BUS_VALUE <= X"38";
                        state <= DROP_LCD_E;
                        next_command <= FUNC_SET;
                    -- EXTRA STATES ABOVE ARE NEEDED FOR RELIABLE PUSHBUTTON RESET OF LCD
                    WHEN FUNC_SET =>
                        LCD_E <= '1';
                        LCD_RS <= '0';
                        LCD_RW_INT <= '0';
                        DATA_BUS_VALUE <= X"38";
                        state <= DROP_LCD_E;
                        next_command <= DISPLAY_OFF;
                    -- Turn off Display and Turn off cursor
                    WHEN DISPLAY_OFF =>
                        LCD_E <= '1';
                        LCD_RS <= '0';
                        LCD_RW_INT <= '0';
                        DATA_BUS_VALUE <= X"08";
                        state <= DROP_LCD_E;
                        next_command <= DISPLAY_CLEAR;
                    -- Clear Display and Turn off cursor
                    WHEN DISPLAY_CLEAR =>
                        LCD_E <= '1';
                        LCD_RS <= '0';
                        LCD_RW_INT <= '0';
                        DATA_BUS_VALUE <= X"01";
                        state <= DROP_LCD_E;
                        next_command <= DISPLAY_ON;
                    -- Turn on Display and Turn off cursor
                    WHEN DISPLAY_ON =>
                        LCD_E <= '1';
                        LCD_RS <= '0';
                        LCD_RW_INT <= '0';
                        DATA_BUS_VALUE <= X"0C";
                        state <= DROP_LCD_E;
                        next_command <= MODE_SET;
                    -- Set write mode to auto increment address and move cursor to the right
                    WHEN MODE_SET =>
                        LCD_E <= '1';
                        LCD_RS <= '0';
                        LCD_RW_INT <= '0';
                        DATA_BUS_VALUE <= X"06";
                        state <= DROP_LCD_E;
                        next_command <= Print_String;
                    -- Write ASCII hex character in first LCD character location
                    WHEN Print_String =>
                        state <= DROP_LCD_E;
                        LCD_E <= '1';
                        LCD_RS <= '1';
                        LCD_RW_INT <= '0';
                        -- ASCII character to output
                        IF Next_Char(7 DOWNTO  4) /= X"0" THEN
                            DATA_BUS_VALUE <= Next_Char;
                        ELSE
                            -- Convert 4-bit value to an ASCII hex digit
                            IF Next_Char(3 DOWNTO 0) >9 THEN
                                -- ASCII A...F
                                DATA_BUS_VALUE <= X"4" & (Next_Char(3 DOWNTO 0)-9);
                            ELSE
                                -- ASCII 0...9
                                DATA_BUS_VALUE <= X"3" & Next_Char(3 DOWNTO 0);
                            END IF;
                        END IF;
                        state <= DROP_LCD_E;
                        -- Loop to send out 32 characters to LCD Display  (16 by 2 lines)
                        IF (CHAR_COUNT < 31) AND (Next_Char /= X"FE") THEN
                            CHAR_COUNT <= CHAR_COUNT +1;
                        ELSE
                            CHAR_COUNT <= "00000";
                        END IF;
                        -- Jump to second line?
                        IF CHAR_COUNT = 15 THEN
                            next_command <= line2;
                        -- Return to first line?
                        ELSIF (CHAR_COUNT = 31) OR (Next_Char = X"FE") THEN
                            next_command <= return_home;
                        ELSE
                            next_command <= Print_String;
                        END IF;
                        -- Set write address to line 2 character 1
                    WHEN LINE2 =>
                        LCD_E <= '1';
                        LCD_RS <= '0';
                        LCD_RW_INT <= '0';
                        DATA_BUS_VALUE <= X"C0";
                        state <= DROP_LCD_E;
                        next_command <= Print_String;
                        -- Return write address to first character postion on line 1
                    WHEN RETURN_HOME =>
                        LCD_E <= '1';
                        LCD_RS <= '0';
                        LCD_RW_INT <= '0';
                        DATA_BUS_VALUE <= X"80";
                        state <= DROP_LCD_E;
                        next_command <= Print_String;
                        -- The next three states occur at the end of each command or data transfer to the LCD
                        -- Drop LCD E line - falling edge loads inst/data to LCD controller
                    WHEN DROP_LCD_E =>
                        LCD_E <= '0';
                        state <= HOLD;
                        -- Hold LCD inst/data valid after falling edge of E line
                    WHEN HOLD =>
                        state <= next_command;
                END CASE;
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END PROCESS;
END Behavior;
```

Comment: Create a top-level design that instantiates the sequence detector and LCD controller ... as components. (Or simpler, as direct entity instantiations). Oh, and fix the sensitivity list on the sequence detector state machine.

Comment: Fix the case statement in the LCD architecture, too  "...each value of the subtype shall be represented once and only once in the set of choices of the case statement." `enable__0` is a std_logic_vector, it needs an `others` choice.

Comment: Ok so to instantiate both as components in the top level entity is what I do not know how to do............do I just build them both as entities and all their atributes will follow, or something else?  Also for the second response I should provide a option when others correct?  meaning if any other value exists.......If that is what you mean.  I think it is.

Comment: and by changing the sensitivity list for the case are you refering to making the process effective on the clock and something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    LIBRARY ieee;
    USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

    ENTITY top_module IS PORT(
        X : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 DOWNTO 0);
        CLK, LOAD: IN STD_LOGIC;
        LCD_RS, LCD_E          : OUT STD_LOGIC;
        LCD_RW                 : OUT   STD_LOGIC;
        LCD_ON                 : OUT STD_LOGIC;
        LCD_BLON               : OUT STD_LOGIC;
        );
    END ENTITY;

    ARCHITECTURE Behavior OF top_module IS

    component Sequence_Detector IS PORT(
        X : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 DOWNTO 0);
        CLK, LOAD: IN STD_LOGIC;
        LED : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(17 DOWNTO 0);
        Z: INOUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0));
    END component;

   component slowclk IS PORT(
        clk : IN STD_LOGIC;
        clkout : OUT STD_LOGIC);
   END component;

   component LCD is PORT(
        reset, CLOCK_50        : IN  STD_LOGIC;
        enable_0               : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0);
        enable_1               : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0);
        LCD_RS, LCD_E          : OUT STD_LOGIC;
        LCD_RW                 : OUT   STD_LOGIC;
        LCD_ON                 : OUT STD_LOGIC;
        LCD_BLON               : OUT STD_LOGIC;
        DATA_BUS               : INOUT  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0));
   END component;


   begin

   Instance_sequence_detector:
         port map ( X => X,
                   CLK => clkout,
                   LOAD => LOAD,
                   LED => LED,
                   Z => Z );

   Instance_slowclk:
     port map ( clk   => clk,
               clkout => clkout
            );

   Instance_LCD:
     port map(reset => reset,
             CLOCK_50 => clkout,
             enable_0 => enable_0,
             enable_1 => enable_1,
             LCD_RS => LCD_RS,
             LCD_E => LCD_E,
             LCD_RW => LCD_RW,
             LCD_ON => LCD_ON,
             LCD_BLON => LCD_BLON,
             DATA_BUS => DATA_BUS
             );
```

You can instantiate those modules in your top module like this. Just map the corresponding in and out ports from block to block.

Comment: Just let me know if it works. You may need to assign few signals here and there for port mapping if required.

Answer (score 0):

I tries embedding the signals into the LCD program and was able to figure it out. I would like to learn how to take care of instantiating the Entities in the future so thank you all for the responses.

Matt

```
    LIBRARY IEEE;
USE  IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
USE  IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.all;
USE  IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.all;

ENTITY State_Machine IS
------------------------------------------------------------------- 
--                        ASCII HEX TABLE
--  Hex                 Low Hex Digit
-- Value  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   A   B   C   D   E   F
------\----------------------------------------------------------------
--H  2 |  SP  !   "   #   $   %   &   '   (   )   *   +   ,   -   .   /
--i  3 |  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   :   ;   <   =   >   ?
--g  4 |  @   A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N   O
--h  5 |  P   Q   R   S   T   U   V   W   X   Y   Z   [   \   ]   ^   _
--   6 |  `   a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k   l   m   n   o
--   7 |  p   q   r   s   t   u   v   w   x   y   z   {   |   }   ~ DEL
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

   PORT(reset, CLOCK_50       : IN  STD_LOGIC;
--       enable                         : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0);
         X                          : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 DOWNTO 0);
         LOAD                           : IN STD_LOGIC;
       LCD_RS, LCD_E          : OUT STD_LOGIC;
       LCD_RW                 : OUT   STD_LOGIC;
       LCD_ON                 : OUT STD_LOGIC;
       LCD_BLON               : OUT STD_LOGIC;
         LED                            : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(17 DOWNTO 0);
       DATA_BUS               : INOUT  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0));
--       W                              : INOUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0));    
END ENTITY;

ARCHITECTURE BEH OF State_Machine IS
TYPE character_string IS ARRAY ( 0 TO 31 ) OF STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0 );
TYPE state_type_1 is (S0,S1,S2,S3,S4,S5,S6,S7,S8);
TYPE STATE_TYPE IS (HOLD, FUNC_SET, DISPLAY_ON, MODE_SET, Print_String,
               LINE2, RETURN_HOME, DROP_LCD_E, RESET1, RESET2, 
               RESET3, DISPLAY_OFF, DISPLAY_CLEAR);

SIGNAL  TMP : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL  clkout : STD_LOGIC;
SIGNAL  Z : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL  state_1 : state_type_1;
SIGNAL   state, next_command           : STATE_TYPE;
SIGNAL   LCD_display_string            : character_string;
SIGNAL   DATA_BUS_VALUE, Next_Char     : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL   CLK_COUNT_400HZ               : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(19 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL   CHAR_COUNT                 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL   CLK_400HZ_Enable,LCD_RW_INT   : STD_LOGIC;
SIGNAL   Line1_chars, Line2_chars      : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(127 DOWNTO 0);

COMPONENT slowclk
    PORT(clock_50 : IN STD_LOGIC;
         clkout : OUT STD_LOGIC);
END COMPONENT;

BEGIN

    LCD_ON <= '1';
    LCD_BLON <= '1';
    LED(17) <= LOAD;
    LED(8 DOWNTO 0) <= X;
    TMP <= X;

    state0: slowclk PORT MAP (clock_50, clkout);

   PROCESS (CLock_50)
   BEGIN
        IF (LOAD = '1') THEN
            IF (clkout'EVENT AND clkout = '1') THEN
                CASE state_1 IS
                    WHEN S0 =>
                        IF X(8) = '0' THEN
                            state_1 <= S0;      --1--
                            Z <= "00";
                        ELSE
                            state_1 <= S1;
                            Z <= "00";
                        END IF;

                    WHEN S1 =>
                        IF X(7) = '0' THEN
                            state_1 <= S0;      --1--
                            Z <= "00";
                        ELSE
                            state_1 <= S2;
                            Z <= "00";
                        END IF;

                    WHEN S2 =>
                        IF X(6) = '0' THEN
                            state_1 <= S3;      --0--
                            Z <= "00";
                        ELSE
                            state_1 <= S2;
                            Z <= "00";
                        END IF;

                    WHEN S3 =>
                        IF X(5) = '0' THEN
                            state_1 <= S0;      --1--
                            Z <= "00";
                        ELSE
                            state_1 <= S4;
                            Z <= "00";
                        END IF;

                    WHEN S4 =>
                        IF X(4) = '0' THEN
                            state_1 <= S5;      --0--
                            Z <= "00";
                        ELSE
                            state_1 <= S2;
                            Z <= "00";
                        END IF;

                    WHEN S5 =>
                        IF X(3) = '0' THEN
                            state_1 <= S6;      --0--
                            Z <= "00";
                        ELSE
                            state_1 <= S0;
                            Z <= "00";
                        END IF;

                    WHEN S6 =>
                        IF X(2) = '0' THEN
                            state_1 <= S0;      --1--
                            Z <= "00";
                        ELSE
                            state_1 <= S7;
                            Z <= "00";
                        END IF;

                    WHEN S7 =>
                        IF X(1) = '0' THEN
                            state_1 <= S0;      --1--
                            Z <= "00";
                        ELSE
                            state_1 <= S8;
                            Z <= "00";
                        END IF;

                    WHEN S8 =>
                        IF X(0) = '0' THEN
                            state_1 <= S0;      --0--
                            Z <= "11";
                        ELSE
                            state_1 <= S2;
                            Z <= "01";
                        END IF;
                END CASE;
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END PROCESS;

    PROCESS (clock_50)
BEGIN
CASE(z) IS
    WHEN "11" => LCD_display_string <= (X"53",X"65",X"71",X"75",X"65",X"6E",X"63",X"65",X"20",X"50",X"61",X"73",X"73",X"65",X"64",X"20",
    X"4D",X"61",X"74",X"74",X"68",X"65",X"77",X"20",X"41",X"6E",X"64",X"65",X"72",X"73",X"6F",X"6E");
    WHEN "10" => LCD_display_string <= (X"20",X"20",X"20",X"20",X"45",X"45",X"43",X"45",X"20",X"33",X"34",X"33",X"20",X"20",X"20",X"20",
    X"4D",X"61",X"74",X"74",X"68",X"65",X"77",X"20",X"41",X"6E",X"64",X"65",X"72",X"73",X"6F",X"6E");
    WHEN "01" => LCD_display_string <= (X"53",X"65",X"71",X"75",X"65",X"6E",X"63",X"65",X"20",X"46",X"61",X"69",X"6C",X"65",X"64",X"20",
    X"4D",X"61",X"74",X"74",X"68",X"65",X"77",X"20",X"41",X"6E",X"64",X"65",X"72",X"73",X"6F",X"6E");
    WHEN "00" => LCD_display_string <= (X"20",X"20",X"20",X"20",X"45",X"45",X"43",X"45",X"20",X"33",X"34",X"33",X"20",X"20",X"20",X"20",
    X"4D",X"61",X"74",X"74",X"68",X"65",X"77",X"20",X"41",X"6E",X"64",X"65",X"72",X"73",X"6F",X"6E");
END CASE;
END PROCESS;
-- ASCII hex values for LCD Display
-- Enter Live Hex Data Values from hardware here
-- LCD DISPLAYS THE FOLLOWING:
------------------------------
--| Count=XX                  |
--| DE2                       |
------------------------------
-- Line 1

-- Line 2


-- BIDIRECTIONAL TRI STATE LCD DATA BUS
   DATA_BUS <= DATA_BUS_VALUE WHEN LCD_RW_INT = '0' ELSE "ZZZZZZZZ";

-- get next character in display string
   Next_Char <= LCD_display_string(CONV_INTEGER(CHAR_COUNT));
   LCD_RW <= LCD_RW_INT;

   PROCESS
   BEGIN
    WAIT UNTIL CLOCK_50'EVENT AND CLOCK_50 = '1';
      IF RESET = '0' THEN
       CLK_COUNT_400HZ <= X"00000";
       CLK_400HZ_Enable <= '0';
      ELSE
            IF CLK_COUNT_400HZ < X"0F424" THEN 
             CLK_COUNT_400HZ <= CLK_COUNT_400HZ + 1;
             CLK_400HZ_Enable <= '0';
            ELSE
             CLK_COUNT_400HZ <= X"00000";
             CLK_400HZ_Enable <= '1';
            END IF;
      END IF;
   END PROCESS;

   PROCESS (CLOCK_50, reset)
   BEGIN
      IF reset = '0' THEN
         state <= RESET1;
         DATA_BUS_VALUE <= X"38";
         next_command <= RESET2;
         LCD_E <= '1';
         LCD_RS <= '0';
         LCD_RW_INT <= '0';

      ELSIF CLOCK_50'EVENT AND CLOCK_50 = '1' THEN
-- State Machine to send commands and data to LCD DISPLAY         
        IF CLK_400HZ_Enable = '1' THEN
         CASE state IS
-- Set Function to 8-bit transfer and 2 line display with 5x8 Font size
-- see Hitachi HD44780 family data sheet for LCD command and timing details
            WHEN RESET1 =>
                  LCD_E <= '1';
                  LCD_RS <= '0';
                  LCD_RW_INT <= '0';
                  DATA_BUS_VALUE <= X"38";
                  state <= DROP_LCD_E;
                  next_command <= RESET2;
                  CHAR_COUNT <= "00000";
            WHEN RESET2 =>
                  LCD_E <= '1';
                  LCD_RS <= '0';
                  LCD_RW_INT <= '0';
                  DATA_BUS_VALUE <= X"38";
                  state <= DROP_LCD_E;
                  next_command <= RESET3;
            WHEN RESET3 =>
                  LCD_E <= '1';
                  LCD_RS <= '0';
                  LCD_RW_INT <= '0';
                  DATA_BUS_VALUE <= X"38";
                  state <= DROP_LCD_E;
                  next_command <= FUNC_SET;
-- EXTRA STATES ABOVE ARE NEEDED FOR RELIABLE PUSHBUTTON RESET OF LCD
            WHEN FUNC_SET =>
                  LCD_E <= '1';
                  LCD_RS <= '0';
                  LCD_RW_INT <= '0';
                  DATA_BUS_VALUE <= X"38";
                  state <= DROP_LCD_E;
                  next_command <= DISPLAY_OFF;
-- Turn off Display and Turn off cursor
            WHEN DISPLAY_OFF =>
                  LCD_E <= '1';
                  LCD_RS <= '0';
                  LCD_RW_INT <= '0';
                  DATA_BUS_VALUE <= X"08";
                  state <= DROP_LCD_E;
                  next_command <= DISPLAY_CLEAR;
-- Clear Display and Turn off cursor
            WHEN DISPLAY_CLEAR =>
                  LCD_E <= '1';
                  LCD_RS <= '0';
                  LCD_RW_INT <= '0';
                  DATA_BUS_VALUE <= X"01";
                  state <= DROP_LCD_E;
                  next_command <= DISPLAY_ON;
-- Turn on Display and Turn off cursor
            WHEN DISPLAY_ON =>
                  LCD_E <= '1';
                  LCD_RS <= '0';
                  LCD_RW_INT <= '0';
                  DATA_BUS_VALUE <= X"0C";
                  state <= DROP_LCD_E;
                  next_command <= MODE_SET;
-- Set write mode to auto increment address and move cursor to the right
            WHEN MODE_SET =>
                  LCD_E <= '1';
                  LCD_RS <= '0';
                  LCD_RW_INT <= '0';
                  DATA_BUS_VALUE <= X"06";
                  state <= DROP_LCD_E;
                  next_command <= Print_String;
-- Write ASCII hex character in first LCD character location
            WHEN Print_String =>
                  state <= DROP_LCD_E;
                  LCD_E <= '1';
                  LCD_RS <= '1';
                  LCD_RW_INT <= '0';
-- ASCII character to output
                  IF Next_Char(7 DOWNTO  4) /= X"0" THEN
                  DATA_BUS_VALUE <= Next_Char;
                  ELSE
-- Convert 4-bit value to an ASCII hex digit
                     IF Next_Char(3 DOWNTO 0) >9 THEN
-- ASCII A...F
                      DATA_BUS_VALUE <= X"4" & (Next_Char(3 DOWNTO 0)-9);
                     ELSE
-- ASCII 0...9
                      DATA_BUS_VALUE <= X"3" & Next_Char(3 DOWNTO 0);
                     END IF;
                  END IF;
                  state <= DROP_LCD_E;
-- Loop to send out 32 characters to LCD Display  (16 by 2 lines)
                  IF (CHAR_COUNT < 31) AND (Next_Char /= X"FE") THEN 
                   CHAR_COUNT <= CHAR_COUNT +1;
                  ELSE 
                   CHAR_COUNT <= "00000"; 
                  END IF;
-- Jump to second line?
                  IF CHAR_COUNT = 15 THEN next_command <= line2;
-- Return to first line?
                  ELSIF (CHAR_COUNT = 31) OR (Next_Char = X"FE") THEN 
                   next_command <= return_home; 
                  ELSE next_command <= Print_String; END IF;
-- Set write address to line 2 character 1
            WHEN LINE2 =>
                  LCD_E <= '1';
                  LCD_RS <= '0';
                  LCD_RW_INT <= '0';
                  DATA_BUS_VALUE <= X"C0";
                  state <= DROP_LCD_E;
                  next_command <= Print_String;
-- Return write address to first character postion on line 1
            WHEN RETURN_HOME =>
                  LCD_E <= '1';
                  LCD_RS <= '0';
                  LCD_RW_INT <= '0';
                  DATA_BUS_VALUE <= X"80";
                  state <= DROP_LCD_E;
                  next_command <= Print_String;
-- The next three states occur at the end of each command or data transfer to the LCD
-- Drop LCD E line - falling edge loads inst/data to LCD controller
            WHEN DROP_LCD_E =>
                  LCD_E <= '0';
                  state <= HOLD;
-- Hold LCD inst/data valid after falling edge of E line          
            WHEN HOLD =>
                  state <= next_command;
         END CASE;
        END IF;
      END IF;
   END PROCESS;
END BEH;

LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

ENTITY slowclk IS
PORT(clock_50 : IN STD_LOGIC;
     clkout : OUT STD_LOGIC);
END slowclk;

ARCHITECTURE ckt OF slowclk IS
BEGIN
PROCESS(clock_50)
VARIABLE cnt : INTEGER RANGE 0 TO 50000000;
BEGIN
    IF clock_50'EVENT AND clock_50='1' THEN 
        IF cnt=50000000 THEN
            cnt:=0;
            clkout<='1';
        ELSE
            cnt:=cnt+1;
            clkout<='0';
        END IF;
    END IF;
END PROCESS;
END ckt;

enter code here
```